# ngx-document-view not working for objectURL

Tags: angular, document

I'm working on view documents page using Angular 8, when user selects a particular document, the document open on the screen so the user can view it.

Below is the my code:

html:

```
         <iframe style="height: 45vh; width:100%; display: block;"
                 ngx-document  src="{{viewAttachment}}"
                 provider="google"></iframe>
```

TS :

```
  async viewDocument(index) {
    const viewDocument = this.uploadedAttachments[index];
    const fileStream = await this.service.getDocument(viewDocument.fileName);
    this.viewAttachment = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(fileStream));
  }
```

Problem: The above code is not showing any file in the iframe

Although the below code works perfectly:

```
<iframe style="height: 45vh; width:100%; display: block;"
 ngx-document src="http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf"
 provider="google"></iframe>
```

but it is not working when I change the `src` from URL to  ObjectURL.

Here is the reference implementation: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-document-view

Note:

I also tried to implement ngx-doc-viewer (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-doc-viewer) in an iframe but I couldn't use it as ngx-doc-viewer does not support local files and blobs/ObjectUrls as stated in the documentation.

I will be happy to provide more information if required. I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Any solution for make it running?